# How can I fix 'communication error' when connecting to Amazon Redshift through Jupyter Notebooks using Python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, amazon-redshift

Hi guys I have a problem while trying to connect to Amazon Redshift through Jupyter Notebooks.
This is my code:

```
conn = redshift_connector.connect(
    host= "redshift-cluster-1.******.eu-west-3.redshift.amazonaws.com",
    database= "dev",
    port = 5439,
    user = ****,
    password = ****
    )
```

The error is the following:

InterfaceError: ('communication error', TimeoutError(10060, 'Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder', None, 10060, None))

I'm pretty new to this subject so any help will be aprreciate it

Thank you

I've try to restart the cluster and creating a new one but it seems that the problem is about the parameters

PD: It's necessary to allow something on the cluster or add some permissions on IAM?

Comment: I believe this is simply that your IP address does not have access to the redshift cluster. if this is just a test setup then you can modify your cluster to allow your ip address.